# numpy ndarray uninitialized values interesting

Tags: python, numpy, initialization

When I create a numpy ndarray,

```
c = np.ndarray((4, 5))
```

I get:

```
c = array([[  6.58119589e-295,               nan,   2.10077583e-312,
      1.08646184e-311,   2.84381388e-308],
   [  1.93933443e-309,   1.20154015e-306,   2.90571629e-298,
     -7.52450413e-266,   3.00029506e-309],
   [  1.75738822e+159,   1.75738821e+159,   2.17292369e-310,
      8.73989988e+245,   1.77863364e+248],
   [  8.65447358e+251,   6.21822202e+175,   2.63920065e-314,
      6.60553537e-295,   6.06307776e-295]])
```

This is pretty interesting to me since all the values are either super large positive or close to zero, and sometimes I can have the NaN there.

What is the mechanism behind?

Is it somehow related to `sys.float_info` which is `sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)`?

Willing to see your opinions.

**UPDATE**:

I see it is garbage in the memory space, but what determines they are interpreted into these numbers? Or say, how python represents floating point numbers?

**UPDATE ON UPDATE**:

I see how floating point numbers work but why these exponents are in a specific pattern?

Comment: I updated my answer with links describing floating points representation. Please make your question more specific, in its updated state it is either too broad or unclear what you ask, hence seems to be off topic for SO.

Comment: would be interesting to see the statistical distribution of them actually, since they are indeed nearly always +-1e150something or something like +-1e300+ or so, and never 1e50 or something like that,

Comment: @usethedeathstar you can do it, it's easy with `np.histogram`. I tend to see zeros ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy allocates needed memory for your array according to it's type (np.float by default). If not initialized, the result you see is tranlation of garbage in allocated memory. Not all possible byte combinations can be converted to float, hence `NaN`, i.e. `Not a Number`.

**Update**

As you ask about floating point representation, read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) or [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

`np.float` is [64 bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) by default:

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float)
finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

On 64b os you can have [float128]:(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision_floating-point_format)

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float128)
finfo(resolution=1e-18, min=-1.18973149536e+4932, max=1.18973149536e+4932, dtype=float128)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), if you call `ndarray` without a `buffer` argument the values it is filled with are random. They recommend using `array`, `zeros` or `empty` to create a new array, rather than the low-level `ndarray`.

Comment: Thanks! But why it is random in that way?